Добавить обязательное поле email при оплате LiqPay на сайте созданном в WIX
Есть сайт созданный на конструкторе Wix. Кодом я вставил на него кнопку оплаты LiqPay. Все работает НО как мне сделать так, что-бы я видел емейл того, кто совершил удачную оплату?
